# Parameters in MVC not being correctly passed into the view from routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm teaching myself MVC and have an issue with routing correctly

I have a controller named "ClipsController" and 1 view inside with the name "Index" (boring, i know)

I have my routeconfig file configured with the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Clips",
    "Clips/{id}",
    new { controller = "Clips", action = "Index", id = urlparameters.Optional }
);
```

which is **Before** the "Default" route. When i go to /Clips/ExampleID
it does hit the correct route, and does start the Index action in the Clips controller. What i'm having trouble with is the parameter 'ID' fails to pass through into the Index page, but i end up on the index action of the Clips controller, with the URL domain.my/Clips/ExampleID

I attempt to get the ID parameter with

```
httpcontext.current.request.querystring["id"]
```

which always returns a null. My actionresult in the controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return view()
}
```

To reiterate, I'm not able to see the querystring id on the index view, even though the URL does the correct route, and the actionresult in the controller is to my kowledge correct. If i have done something critically wrong or you need more information please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: what is the url you tried ? `youriste.com/clips/anystring` should work with the information you provided.

Comment: That's why your action takes the param, `id`. This will be filled in with the value from the route, so that is what you should use within your action. In the URL you're accessing there is no querystring, so attempting to access anything from `QueryString` will return null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I attempt to get the ID parameter with
>
> httpcontext.current.request.querystring["id"]

No, you don't have any query string parameters in this url:

```
http://domain.my/Clips/ExampleID
```

Query string parameters follow the `?` character in an url. For example if you had the following url:

```
http://domain.my/Clips?id=ExampleID
```

then you could attempt to read the `id` query string parameter using your initial code.

With this url: `http://domain.my/Clips/ExampleID` you could query the `id` route value parameter. But using `HttpContext.Current` is absolutely the wrong way to do it. You should never use `HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET MVC application. Quite on the contrary, you can access this information everywhere where you have access to `HttpContextBase` (which is pretty much everywhere in the ASP.NET MVC application pipeline):

```
httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Long story short, if you needed to query the value of this parameter inside your controller action you would simply use the provided `id` argument:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    // Here the id argument will map to ExampleID
    return view()
}
```

Also you probably don't need your custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Clips",
    "Clips/{id}",
    new { controller = "Clips", action = "Index", id = urlparameters.Optional }
);
```

That's completely redundant and it is already covered by the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So feel more than free to get rid of your custom route.

Comment: I want to use a custom route for learning purposes, I knew the default would catch it, i just wanted to make it not show clips/index/id.

so for the url 'domain.my/clips/IdIWantToGet'

i would use the 

     httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] 

and it would return the string 'IdIWantToGet'?

Comment: Yes, if you needed to access this value somewhere outside your controller action. Inside your controller action you could simply use the `id` argument. But you haven't quite specified where exactly you need to access this value. If you need it inside the view then obviously you will not use `httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]`. You would use a view model inside your controller action that will have an ID property populated from the `id` argument that your controller action takes.

Comment: Okay, this has helped me understand the MVC process a bit more, so i'll give you the correct answer. Thank you very much